# Supabase (Postgres) Row Level Security Based on Role in Table

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I'm new to [Supabase](https://supabase.com) and Postgres (though not new to SQL) but I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around writing policies.

Let's say I have a `member` table structured like this:

```dart
// member //

id (text) | name (text) | group (text) | admin (int)
----------------------------------------------------
abc       | Bob         | alpha        | 0
----------------------------------------------------
xyz       | Sally       | bravo        | 1
----------------------------------------------------
```

The `id` in the `member` table matches the `id` of the authenticated users of my app.

I want to restrict other tables in my database based on group:

```dart
// program //

id (text) | name (text) | group (text)
--------------------------------------
def       | First       | alpha     
--------------------------------------
ghi       | Second      | bravo     
--------------------------------------
```

**Desired policy #1:**

> Allow any user to `SELECT` if they are in the program's `group`.

**Desired policy #2:**

> Allow any user to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` if they are in the program's `group` **and** if they are an `admin`.

I think I'm supposed to write a `USING` statement that is something like:

```sql
SELECT program 
WHERE group IN (
  SELECT group 
  FROM member 
  WHERE member.id == auth().id
)
```

...and then a similar one for policy #2 that adds `AND member.admin = 1`, but I'm not clear on this.

Am I on the right track? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are perfectly on track! You should be able to just paste the following section in your Supabase dashboard policy editor to get it working.

```sql
group IN (
  SELECT group 
  FROM member 
  WHERE member.id == auth().id
)
```

You can also run the following SQL from the SQL editor of the dashboard to get the same results.

```sql
create policy "Users can view data of their group"
  on program
  for select using (
    group IN (
      SELECT group 
      FROM member 
      WHERE member.id == auth.uid()
    )
  );
```